# Fire method each time route slug changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a Router set up which looks like this:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts', function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'});
    });
});
```

When the `account` route is entered I'm using the activate method to do some DOM manipulation.

```
Social.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function(){
        console.log('entered the account route')
    }
});
```

This works great, the first time the account route is entered. Problem is that I have the ability to change from account to account without leaving the account route. Meaning that I can go from:

```
account/1
```

to

```
account/2
```

but the activate method only fires one time, the first time I enter the account route. Is there a method that will fire every time the account_id slug changes?

Answer (score 4):

Not a very intuitive solution, but there are 3 methods that are executed every time the model changes:

- serialize
- setupController
- renderTemplate

Answer (score 2):

`activate` and `deactivate` are only triggered when entering a new route. However, the methods `model`, `setupController`, and `serialize` will be called with each change of `/account/:account_id`. *(Edit: as pointed out by @mavilein in the comments, `model` will only be called when triggered by a URL change, and I left off `renderTemplate`).*

Regardless, your routes and controllers shouldn't be concerned with DOM manipulation. Leave that to your views and templates by binding to significant values or observing changes in your controller(s).

Comment: That's a good point Dan. So if I needed to do DOM manipulation I should place that within the AccountController init method?

Comment: The model hook is just executed when the app is entered via URL.

Comment: DOM Mnaipulation should completely reside in your views.

Comment: Yes, I left off `renderTemplate` - and it does depend on how the route is entered whether `model` will be called. Points to @mavilein! But like we've both said, DOM manipulation should only happen in your view/template layer.